# What is A2L refractive index polynomial?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, software

I'm working with a photonic modelling software and in the manual I saw that I can specify refractive index of modelled material with following polynomial:

$$n(\lambda)=c_0+c_1/(\lambda-\lambda_0)+c_2/(\lambda-\lambda_0)^2. $$

It's described in manual as A2L. No more informations. I was searching the internet looking for it, but I haven't found anything about it.

So what is that equation? How is it named? What are it's limitations? What are the $c$ constants? Where to find more details about it?

Comment: It's not quite Cauchy and not quite Sellmeier... What software is it?

Comment: @lemontwist It's called "Omnisim".